# SSRS default date expression

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I have `FROM` and `TO` date parameters. I need to assign default values for them.

For example, if we run the report today (12 September), the default values for `FROM` and `TO` should be 10/01/2016 and 03/31/2017. as the current month (9) satisfies in the second condition below:

Based on the report run date (current date):

```
IF Month                       then From Date               and To Date
>=1 and <=3                    4/1/prior yr                 9/30/prior yr
>=4 and <= 9                   10/1/prior yr                3/31/curr yr
>=10 and <=12                  4/1/curr yr                  9/30/curr yr
```

Could you tell me the SSRS expression?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems I finally understood what you want.

Create a dataset `date_parameters` with the following query:

```
select case when month(getdate()) <= 3 then '4/1/' + cast (year(getdate()) - 1 as char(4))
            when month(getdate()) <= 9 then '10/1/' + cast (year(getdate()) - 1 as char(4))
            when month(getdate()) <= 12 then '4/1/' + cast (year(getdate()) as char(4))
       end as from_date,
       case when month(getdate()) <= 3 then '9/30/' + cast (year(getdate()) - 1 as char(4))
            when month(getdate()) <= 9 then '3/31/' + cast (year(getdate()) as char(4));
            when month(getdate()) <= 12 then '9/30/' + cast (year(getdate()) as char(4))
       end as to_date
```

[image]

Then in your default parameter values choose the option `Get values from a query`
Specify your `date_parameters` dataset and choose `from_date` for your `FROM DATE` parameter and the same dataset but `to_date` as value for `TO DATE` parameter

[image]

And here is the result:

[image]

P.S. Adjust case constants as you need (with padding zeros), only now I noticed that in the question you wrote `10/1/2017` but in the comment it became `10/01/2017`. I used your constants from the question, i.e. without zeros

Comment: Just wondering:  You're output creates string values.   Don't you have to cast the resulting strings as dates to get the correct comparison logic?

Comment: That is just what he was asking for. Personally I never use other format than yyyymmdd for ** values** (and for labels I use dd/mm/yyyy that is format used in my country)